# Can you have code before the mutex lock_guard within the same block

Tags: c++, mutex

So, this is probably an obvious answer, but I just have a doubt because I have not seen it used...

So, with normal mutex usage you can do:

```
void func1()
{
    mymutex.lock();
    // do func1 stuff on shared data
    mymutex.unlock();
}

void func2()
{
    func1(); // also uses mymutex

    mymutex.lock();
    // do func2 stuff on shared data
    mymutex.unlock();
}
```

Where we can see the start/end of the mutex sections easily.

But with lock_guard can you do the same thing, i.e.:

```
void func1()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(mymutex);
    // do func1 stuff on shared data
}

void func2()
{
    func1(); // also uses lock_guard on mymutex

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(mymutex);
    // do func2 stuff on shared data
}
```

Here, my doubt is that usually you use lock_guard to guard a complete c++ block. But in func2 I first call func1 (which itself uses the same mutex) and then I call lock_gaurd in the **same** block but **after** calling func1.

Is that ok/safe to do? or does lock_guard in func2 have some affect on func1?

I initially assumed it was ok - but then my brain started telling me this locks suspicious. I could easily stick a block around the func2 lock_guard - but now I need to know if its ok or not before I can sleep again :o

Comment: `lock_guard` are nothing mystical, there are RAII wrapper for `std::mutex`. If `g` was a `std::vector` in `func1`, do you expect its memory to be released at the end of `func1` or at the end of `func2`? The same apply to a `std::lock_guard` expect that instead of releasing memory, it releases a mutex.

Comment: It's ok since `g` is created, and locked, where it declared, not before `func1().`

Comment: @Holt I was more worried about func2's lock_guard somehow covering func1 because its in the same block (yeah, sounds a bit silly now - but that it was my brain was telling me!)

Comment: @sklott - exactly the words I was looking for : ) thanks

Comment: @code_fodder The same analogy apply then, if `g` was a vector in `func2`, do you expect it to allocate memory before or after the call to `func1`? :)

Comment: lol....no I would not : )  as I say, I think it was just an irrational fear that it was wrong! thanks : )

Comment: @Holt and sklott - please feel free to update with answers I will mark them up as they both give good clarity on top of nivpeleds answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is safe. Please go to sleep now :)

The unlock functionality is being executed automatically for you when the lock guard is terminated (when its scope is exited)

see more [here](https://doc.bccnsoft.com/docs/cppreference2015/en/cpp/thread/lock_guard.html)

> The class lock_guard is a mutex wrapper that provides a convenient
>   RAII-style mechanism for owning a mutex for the duration of a scoped
>   block.
>
> *When a lock_guard object is created, it attempts to take ownership of the mutex it is given. **When control leaves the scope in which the
>   lock_guard object was created, the lock_guard is destructed and the
>   mutex is released.***
>
> The lock_guard class is non-copyable.

Comment: pheww.... thanks for that, I am not sure why, but I was worried that func2's lock_guard was initialise *before* calling func1()... but I am happy that is not the case - silly brain : )

Comment: @code_fodder, in certain cases it's possible for the compiler or the cpu to reorder instructions to make them more efficient. If you haven't done so already, please read about memory model and reordering. For example https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/

Comment: @code_fodder and this might also be relevant: https://preshing.com/20170612/can-reordering-of-release-acquire-operations-introduce-deadlock/

Comment: @rashmatash operations with mutexes can't be reordered, otherwise it would lead to bugs.

Comment: your link is broken, and in case the last paragraph is quoted from somewhere, please use the blockquote formatting